# Why my code palindrome works only for single input not for many inputs?

Tags: python, palindrome

A palindrome is a word or a phrase that is the same when read both forward and backward. Examples are: "bob," "sees," or "never odd or even" (ignoring spaces). Write a program whose input is a word or phrase, and that outputs whether the input is a palindrome.

I'm only getting this half right. my code is working for bob, and sees.
When an input is "never odd or even" my code doesn't work it shows is not a palindrome but it should be a palindrome.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
word = str(input())
new = word.replace(" ", "")
new = new[::-1]

if word == new:
    print('{} is a palindrome'.format(word))
else:
    print('{} is not a palindrome'.format(word))
```

Comment: Probably because you are not replacing spaces in `word`

Comment: `word` still contains spaces.

Comment: Change `new = new[::-1]` to `reversed = new[::-1]` and then `if word == new:` to `if reversed == new:`.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `word` with `new`, but to generate `new` you had removed all the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of line `new = word.replace(" ", "")` - the `word` is kept with the spaces in it. You should make a version of `word` with no spaces, reverse that, then compare it with the no-spaces `word`.

Something like:

```
  word = str(input())
  spaceless_word = word.replace(" ", "")
  new = spaceless_word[::-1]

  if spaceless_word == new:
      print('{} is a palindrome'.format(word))
  else:
      print('{} is not a palindrome'.format(word))
```

Comment: That works! I see where I did mistake

Comment: Glad this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
word = str(input())
word = word.replace(" ", "")
new = word
new = new[::-1]

if word == new:
    print('{} is a palindrome'.format(word))
else:
    print('{} is not a palindrome'.format(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer, kinda ugly but I just kept adding stuff until it was right.

```py
inputs=str(input())
inputs_nospace=inputs.replace(' ', '')
inputs_reversed=inputs_nospace
inputs_reversed=inputs_reversed[::-1]
if inputs_reversed==inputs_nospace:
    print (inputs, 'is a palindrome')
else:
    print(inputs, 'is not a palindrome')
```

Comment: This is same as foobarna's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although other code may work this is the code I used to make sure I got everything correct. I didn't even have to use stack overflow. Rare

```
user_input = input() # get user input...
bare = user_input.strip().lower().split( ) # did this so even uppercase letters will be able to be palindromes
                                            #though the lab didn't even test that...
text = ''.join(bare) # this removes all space and will be used when compared with reverse_text
reverse_text = text[::-1] # U guessed it this is text reversed
if text != reverse_text: # simple if statement which checks to see if text == reverse_text
    print("not a palindrome:", user_input) # print statement to get full marks on lab
else: # i might be writing too much, but the else statement will only execute if text == reverse_text
    print("palindrome:", user_input) # and print statement to get full marks.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
og_word = str(input())
word = og_word
word = word.replace(" ", "")
new = word
new = new[::-1]

if word == new:
    print(f'palindrome: {og_word}')
else:
    print(f'not a palindrome: {og_word}')
```

Comment: Hi Jose, this answer would benefit frhaving additional context added explaining why you think this will resolve the issue.